# How to share url from android app with image preview

Tags: kotlin, url, share, implicit

I want to create a share sheet just like the share exist in google store , as you can see  [here is google store sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh5EU.png)

currently I am using this code :

```
    ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
        .setType("text/plain")
        .setText("TITLE\nhttp://www.url.com")
        .startChooser()
```

but I am not able to set an image in the share sheet, the result of my implementation:
[my implementation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIXra.png)

Comment: Please, consider updating your question giving a more detailed explanation. Without an example of your bottom sheet, and some more code, it's hard to help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ItzDavi done , is it clear now ?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with your result. Maybe I'm wrong but I think that if you modify your app's icon, also this image should change. Give it a try.

Comment: @ItzDavi I just tried this , but still I have the same result . :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was just on adding the title inside set text  :

```
 ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setText("TITLE\nhttp://www.url.com")
    .startChooser()
```

so the solution is to remove it to be , so the OS will be able to read the url content from it :

```
 ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setText("http://www.url.com")
    .startChooser()
```